# regex replace first element

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have the need to replace a HTML string's contents from one `<br>` to two. But what I can't achieve is when I have one tag following another one:

`(<br\s*\/?>)`

will match all the tags in this text:

```
var text = 'text<BR><BR>text text<BR>text;'
```

will match and with the replace I will have

```
text = text.replace.replace(/(<br\s*\/?>)>/gi, "<BR\/><BR\/>")

console.log(text); //text<BR/><BR/><BR/><BR/>text text<BR/><BR/>text;"
```

Is there a way to only increment one tag with the regex? And achieve this:

```
console.log(text); //text<BR/><BR/><BR/>text text<BR/><BR/>text;"
```

Or I only will achieve this with a loop?

Comment: Do you want to hard code `<BR/>` in the replacement? Don't you want to just add the same `br` that was used last in the sequence? I have just tried and got `text<BR><BR><BR>text text<BR><BR>text;`

Comment: what you want as output?

Comment: text<BR/><BR/><BR/>text text<BR/><BR/>text;

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't need to hard code the <BR/>, if I can only increment with one more br tag should work too;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use either

```js
var text = 'text<BR><BR>text text<BR>text;'
text = text.replace(/(<br\s*\/?>)+/gi, "$&$1");
console.log(text); // => text<BR><BR><BR>text text<BR><BR>text;
```

Here, `(<br\s*\/?>)+/gi` matches 1 or more sequences of `<br>`s in a case insensitive way while capturing each tag on its way (keeping the last value in the group beffer after the last it, and `"$&$1"` will replace with the whole match (`$&`) and will add the last `<br>` with `$1`.

Or

```js
var text = 'text<BR><BR>text text<BR>text;'
text = text.replace(/(?:<br\s*\/?>)+/gi, function ($0) {
 return $0.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gi, "<BR/>") + "<BR/>";
})
console.log(text); // => text<BR/><BR/><BR/>text text<BR/><BR/>text;
```

Here, the `(?:<br\s*\/?>)+` will also match 1 or more `<br>`s but without capturing each occurrence, and inside the callback, all `<br>`s will get normalized as `<BR/>` and a `<BR/>` will get appended to the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative look ahead `(<br\s*\/?>)(?!<br\s*\/?>)/` to increment only the last tag if there are any consecutive:

```js
var text = 'text<BR><BR>text text<BR>text;'

text = text.replace(/(<br\s*\/?>)(?!<br\s*\/?>)/gi, "<BR\/><BR\/>")

console.log(text);
```